# Java ByteArrayOutputStream into a different container

Tags: java, zip, byte

Can `ByteArrayOutputStream` be stored into some other container like say HashMap?

If not how do I merge all my streams and then **zip archive by entries** into 1 file.

```
public class CFr { 

  private static HashMap<String, Object> fileEntries;

  public static void setFileEntries(String fileNameEntry, Object fileEntry) {
    CFr.fileEntries.put(fileNameEntry, fileEntry);
  }

}

public void addDocx(CDb cd) {
  CFr.setFileEntries((String)entryName, (ByteArrayOutputStream)bos);
}
```

And I get NullPointer on that `setFileEntries` line. Doesn't seem right, I was just assuming it is possible.

Comment: if nothing is said,or if this is too ridiculous I will just reverse my logic no problem

Comment: Well have you tried anything yet? Research should come *before* asking a question. If you're asking whether something is possible, you should try it first before asking.

Comment: Believe me I tried, but from all that I manages to find was merging byteArrayInputStreams into SequenceStream (many to one), or merging several Byte[] arrays into one.. doesn't fit

Comment: So show us what you tried, and what went wrong. We don't know what you're trying to achieve, or how you tried using collections for that.

Comment: Nullpointer is because you haven't initialized your `fileEntries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be stored, but you will need to initialize your `HashMap` for that purpose. In your case this

```
  private static HashMap<String, Object> fileEntries;
```

is never initialized. You will need to do something like this:

```
private static HashMap<String, Object> fileEntries = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

instead. This will fix your current issue.

Comment: @abc you are welcome, I wish you the best of luck with your projects.